# python 3.2 html parser

Tags: python, html-parsing, python-3.2

Im relative new python im trying the html.parser as fallow:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request


class TestParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start Tag: ", tag, attrs)
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("End Tag: ", tag)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Data: ", data)
    def handle_startendtag(self,tag,attrs):
        print("StarEnd Tag: ", tag, attrs)

class DanParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DanParser, self).__init__(strict = False)
        self.in_select = False


    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start Tag: ", tag, attrs)
        if tag == "select":
            self.in_select = True
            print("Start Tag: ", tag, attrs)


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("EndTag: ", tag)
        if tag == "select" and self.in_select:
            self.in_select = False
            print("EndTag: ", tag)


    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Data: ", data)
        if self.in_select:
            print("Data: ", data)


    def handle_startendtag(self,tag,attrs):
        print("StarEnd Tag: ", tag, attrs)
```

When i do in the interpreter

```
t = new DanParser()
t.feed("<select>test</select>")
```

im getting:

```
Data:  <select>
Data:  test
EndTag:  select
```

the method handle_starttag is not been called, but when i do it using the TestParser its behaving correctly.
Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong!!!
thanks

Comment: What does `string=False` mean?  According to the docs HTMLParser doesn't take arguments. Also `t = new DanParser()` is a syntax error and your indentation is incorrect.  Fixing these and your example works for me.

Comment: BTW if this is real code and not just practice you should consider using lxml python lib for the html parsing..  and requests library instead of urllib

Comment: @aquavitae: [`HTMLParser()` has `strict` argument](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/html.parser.html?highlight=htmlparser#html.parser.HTMLParser) since Python3.2

Comment: [the code works](http://ideone.com/eBHFT)

Comment: i just check it your link, quite interesting that its working, but i can ensure you that its not working on my computer.
could be this a problem with my interpreter or source code file text encoding

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the strict=False.  When strict=False, start handlers are not called.  They are called when strict=True.  This may be a bug in python's HTMLParser.  moul's example works as he uses the default True value for strict.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me :

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class DanParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.in_select = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start Tag: ", tag, attrs)
        if tag == "select":
            self.in_select = True
            print("Start Tag: ", tag, attrs)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("EndTag: ", tag)
        if tag == "select" and self.in_select:
            self.in_select = False
            print("EndTag: ", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Data: ", data)
        if self.in_select:
            print("Data: ", data)

    def handle_startendtag(self,tag,attrs):
        print("StarEnd Tag: ", tag, attrs)

t = DanParser()
t.feed("<select>test</select>")
```

Comment: i changed the implementation of DanParser with out implementing the constructor and it works as expected, any way i will try your solution.
I can't explain way this problem calling the base class.
Thank you very much to all of you

Answer (score 1):

Tip: make it easy for yourself and do not use this. Try [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html),  [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)